# Palindrome checker in python, out of range index workaround

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I am trying to make this program work without using reverse or sort functions in python 3. It is simply supposed to check for palindromes. The problem I am running into is that I get an index out of range everytime I run it. Is there a way to work around this?

```
def is_palindrome(word):
    if len(word) <= 1:
        return True
    else:
        left = 0
        right = len(word) - 1
        while left < right:
            if word[left] == word[right]:
                left += 1
                right += 1
            else:
                return False
        return True

is_palindrome("mom")
is_palindrome("root")
is_palindrome("racecar")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`right += 1` should be `right -= 1`.

Comment: Thank you, this small mistake cost me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it a bit more succinctly.

```
>>> def is_palin(w):
...     return len(w) <= 1 or (w[0] == w[-1] and is_palin(w[1:-1]))              
... 
>>> is_palin("xax")
True
>>> is_palin("xaax")
True
>>> is_palin("xaab")
False
```